# In Recycler view, Image is not displayed until I touch the screen or turn off and then on the screen again

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on an application that has an end-to-end encrypted chat feature. I have already completed the text part, but I am encountering a weird bug with images.

The image is decrypted successfully, but it is not displayed on the screen until I touch the screen or turn off and then turn on the mobile screen again.

The code runs perfectly for decryption, but the problem arises after assigning the decrypted image to the recycler view.

```
private fun receivingData() {
        try {
            DatabaseAdapter.chatTable.child(receiverRoom).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    chats.clear()

                    if(snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (s in snapshot.children) {
                            val data: ChatModel = s.getValue(ChatModel::class.java)!!

                            if(data.MESSAGE?.contains("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com")!!)
                            {
                                DatabaseAdapter.downloadImageAndConvertToUri(applicationContext,
                                    data.MESSAGE!!
                                )
                                    .thenAccept { uri ->
                                        // Use the URI for further processing, such as decryption
                                        val decryptedUri = DatabaseAdapter.decryptImage(uri, sharedSecret, applicationContext)
                                        data.MESSAGE = decryptedUri.toString()
                                        Log.d("IMG_ERROR","AAA${data.MESSAGE}")
                                        // Perform further operations with the decrypted URI
                                        chats.add(data)
                                        chatAdapter.notifyItemInserted(chats.size)
                                        Log.d("IMG_ERROR","Runs before data")
                                        b.rvChatAct.scrollToPosition(chatAdapter.itemCount-1)
                                    }
                                    .exceptionally { throwable ->
                                        // Handle exceptions that occurred during the download and conversion process
                                        Log.e("Error", "Error downloading and converting image: ${throwable.message}")
                                        null
                                    }
                            }
                            else {
                                data.MESSAGE =
                                    DatabaseAdapter.decryptMessage(data.MESSAGE!!, sharedSecret)
                                Log.d("IMG_ERROR","ABA${data.MESSAGE}")
                                chats.add(data)
                                chatAdapter.notifyItemInserted(chats.size)
                                b.rvChatAct.scrollToPosition(chatAdapter.itemCount-1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
        }catch(e:Exception)
        {
            Log.d("DB_ERROR",e.toString())
        }
    }
```

Here is my chatAdapter code

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        Log.d("IMG_ERROR","aa${chats[position].MESSAGE!!}")
        return if(chats[position].SENDER_KEY.equals(DatabaseAdapter.key)) {
            if(chats[position].MESSAGE!!.contains("project.social.whisper"))
                SENDER_VIEW_IMAGE_TYPE
            else
                SENDER_VIEW_TYPE
        } else {
            if(chats[position].MESSAGE!!.contains("project.social.whisper"))
                RECEIVER_VIEW_IMAGE_TYPE
            else
                RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE
        }
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val m = chats[position]
        val d = Date(m.TIMESTAMP!!)

        val f = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())

        when (holder.javaClass) {
            SenderChatHolder::class.java -> {
                val h = holder as SenderChatHolder
                Log.d("IMG_ERROR","WTH${m.MESSAGE}")
                h.senderMessage.text = m.MESSAGE
                h.senderTime.text = f.format(d)
            }
            ReceiverChatHolder::class.java -> {
                val h = holder as ReceiverChatHolder
                h.receiverMessage.text = m.MESSAGE
                h.receiverTime.text = f.format(d)
            }
            SenderImageChatHolder::class.java -> {
                Log.d("IMG_ERROR","ABCD${m.MESSAGE.toString()}")

                val h = holder as SenderImageChatHolder
                Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(m.MESSAGE)).into(h.senderImgMessage)
                h.senderImgTime.text = f.format(d)

                h.senderImgMessage.setOnClickListener {
                    val i = Intent(context, ImageViewActivity::class.java)
                    i.putExtra("img",m.MESSAGE)
                    context.startActivity(i)
                }

            }
            ReceiverImageChatHolder::class.java -> {
                Log.d("IMG_ERROR",m.MESSAGE.toString())
                Log.d("IMG_ERROR",Uri.parse(m.MESSAGE).toString())
                val h = holder as ReceiverImageChatHolder
                Glide.with(context).load(m.MESSAGE).into(h.receiverImgMessage)
                h.receiverImgTime.text = f.format(d)

                h.receiverImgMessage.setOnClickListener {
                    val i = Intent(context, ImageViewActivity::class.java)
                    i.putExtra("img",m.MESSAGE)
                    context.startActivity(i)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Text based chat works perfectly, I dont need to touch the screen...

Also here is log output of "IMG_ERROR" before I touched the screen :

```
ABAHello
ABAhi
aahi
WTHhi
aaHello
WTHHello
aahi
aaHello
Input Encrypted Image Size: 322752
Decrypted Data Size: 242052
AAAcontent://project.social.whisper.provider/temp/temp_image0.jpg
```

After I touched the screen added log (hi and Hello is chat text, and content... is img uri):

```
aahi
aaHello
aacontent://project.social.whisper.provider/temp/temp_image0.jpg
ABCDcontent://project.social.whisper.provider/temp/temp_image0.jpg
aahi
aaHello
aacontent://project.social.whisper.provider/temp/temp_image0.jpg
aacontent://project.social.whisper.provider/temp/temp_image0.jpg
aahi
aaHello
aacontent://project.social.whisper.provider/temp/temp_image0.jpg
aahi
aaHello
```

Also one more thing, The log : Log.d("IMG_ERROR","Runs before data")
Never appears, even after I touch the screen...

So, I tried to move notifyItemInserted method into if condition as you can see in code, but it didnt work, I also wait for image to appear by it self without I touched the screen , but even after a 2 minutes, Image was not displayed, after touching the screen, It immediately displayed....